# Pandas/Dask: Filter dataframe from multiindex or two other columns of a second dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dask, multi-index, dask-dataframe

Assuming a

```
grouped_id_date = ddf.groupby(['my_id', 'my_date']).count().compute()
```

, we receive a new `DataFrame`, which counts the rows of existence for each pair:

```
+------------+------------+----+-------------------+
|   my_id    |  my_date   | || | my_value (random) |
+------------+------------+----+-------------------+
| MultiIndex | MultiIndex | || | Normal Column     |
| A          | 2020-06-03 | || | 5                 |
| A          | 2020-06-04 | || | 3                 |
| B          | 2020-06-03 | || | 3                 |
| C          | 2020-06-04 | || | 4                 |
+------------+------------+----+-------------------+
```

Now I would like to go back to `ddf` to only `.loc` such rows, which have a `my_count >3`. What would be a good way to achive this?

My current solution is this, which works, but it is like.. well there needs to be a better way:

```
condition = None
for i, my_id_mdate_combi_data in enumerate(grouped_id_date.iterrows()): 
    if i == 1000:
        break # not sure where MaxRecursion Exceptions kicks in..
    my_id = grouped_id_date.index[i][0]
    mdate = grouped_id_date.index[i][1]
    if condition is None:
        condition = ((ddf.my_id == my_id) & (ddf.my_date == my_date))
    else:
        condition = condition | ((ddf.my_id == my_id) & (ddf.my_date == my_date))

result = ddf.loc[condition] # Works, but slow and you reach MaxRecursion Exceptions somewhere.
```

The dataframe counts 500.000.000 rows, so there should not be too much shuffeling and so on..

Comment: you want to do `...groupby(['my_id', 'my_date']).filter(lambda g: g.shape[0]  > 3)`

Comment: Yes.. That would most likely the `my_count >3` condition. But how could I then filter the original `ddf` based on these conditions?

Comment: `ddf.groupby(['my_id', 'my_date']).filter(lambda g: g.shape[0]  > 3)` with a `dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` throws `AttributeError: 'Column not found: filter'`. Validated via `dir`, that `filter` is not a valid operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I come around with:

```
QS_MIN_ROWS_PER_GROUP = 3

# Build groups for each my_date+my_id combination (take a look whats in there)
grouped_myid_mydate = ddf_c.groupby(['my_id', 'my_date'])

# Count amount of occurrences on that day in that id.
quotes_per_myid_mydate_all = grouped_myid_mydate.count().compute()

# Apply filter based on groupby (this now actually compares the rows per group with a pre-defined threshold).
qs_myid_mydate_combinations = quotes_per_myid_mydate_all.loc[quotes_per_myid_mydate_all.my_id>QS_MIN_ROWS_PER_GROUP]

# Get valid pairs from MultiIndex
valid_pairs = qs_myid_mydate_combinations.index.tolist()

# Build list which is searchable by a newly addded search column, which contains both values of the two columns to compare with.. Nasty

valid_pairs_formated = []
for pair in valid_pairs:
    valid_pairs_formated.append('%s;%s' % (pair[0], pair[1]))
print(valid_pairs_formated)

# Add new search-column to central `DataFrame`. This assumes no ';' in the columns!
ddf_c['pair_code'] = (ddf_c.my_id + ';' + ddf_c.my_date.astype(str))
```

Then we could filter `pair_code` on `valid_pairs_formated`:

```
is_in_valid_set_of_combinations = ddf_c.pair_code.isin(valid_pairs_formated)
```

Lets see if the results look reasonable:

```
is_in_valid_set_of_combinations.value_counts().compute() # you can skip this

>> Output:
True     246641219
False        11377
Name: pair_code, dtype: int64
```

Yep ok good.

```
# Lastly reach target: Filter the original DataFrame
ddf_c = ddf_c.loc[ddf_c.is_in_valid_set_of_combinations == True]

# And finally check the row count
len(ddf_c.index)
> 246641219

# And remove that nasty search column:
ddf_c = ddf_c.drop(columns=['pair_code'])
```

A lot of code, for an 'n'-column compare... But it works.

Comment: How fast was the operation? I am assuming it was computationally expensive to filter multiple times on a large dataset.

Comment: Not sure what the runtime was, but it was definitely acceptable fast.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```py
  grouped_id_date = grouped_id_date[grouped_id_date['my_value'] > 3]  
  valid_pairs = grouped_id_date.index.tolist()
  all_pairs = list(ddf[['my_id', 'my_date']].values)
  mask = [(my_id, my_date) in valid_pairs for (my_id, my_date) in all_pairs]

  result = ddf[mask]
```

The idea is to build your own boolean index. You know that all pairs in the grouped data must be present in the original dataframe `ddf`. You exctract the MultiIndex with all valid pairs to a list. Then you extract all pairs from ddf and check if they are present.

*Disclaimer: I did not test this code. The logic should be correct, but there may be a hidden typo resulting in a SyntaxError or similar.*

Comment: This would basically involve a type convertition from `MultiIndex` into `list`. Will give it a try.

Comment: ... and also a convertion from all `ddf[['my_id', 'my_date']]` to `list`. Which invokes a re-type and memory-allocation of all 500.000.000 rows. Trying it now, but it is pretty slow..

Answer (score 0):

If you really know your data, you could also make some assumptions to build a numeric function, which is faster to compute and filter on:

We assume `my_id` to be smaller then 100000 and can build a new column `pair_code_numeric`:

```
PAIR_CODE_OFFSET_FOR_SID = 100000
col_name = 'pair_code_numeric'
ddf_c[col_name] = ((ddf_c.index.dt.year * (10000 * PAIR_CODE_OFFSET_FOR_SID)) + (ddf_c.index.dt.month * (100 * PAIR_CODE_OFFSET_FOR_SID)) + ((ddf_c.index.dt.day) * PAIR_CODE_OFFSET_FOR_SID) + ddf_c.s_id)
```

So what comes out is:

```
# view data without e0x formatting
ddf_c[col_name].apply(lambda x: '%0.f' % x, meta='int64').head()

2019-05-22 09:10:00.011433    2019052200210
2019-05-22 09:10:03.690125    2019052200175
2019-05-22 09:10:04.160046    2019052200448
```

Then the rest is straight-forward `groupby` & `locate` on a single column -

`.groupby`first:

```
v = True
grouped_pair_code = ddf_c.groupby([col_name])
# Count amount of rows in that pair code 
# (One a approach chosen here, but you can apply the method for everything).
quotes_per_pair_code_all = grouped_pair_code.count().compute()
if v: print('Got %s %s combintions before Q/S' % (quotes_per_pair_code_all.shape[0], col_name))

# Get valid combinations from pair_code_numeric from the groupby by counting the numbers per group. Minimum is a hundred rows (that is what is in qs_pair_code_combinations).
qs_pair_code_combis = qs_pair_code_combinations(quotes_per_pair_code_all=quotes_per_pair_code_all,                    QS_MIN_L1_ROWS_PER_DAY = 100, v=False)
ddf_c = client.persist(ddf_c)
```

Output:

```
Got 3467 pair_code_numeric combintions before Q/S
Got 2646 valid pair_code_numeric_combis
```

Then we can simply `.loc` to create a new column, which shows if the row is valid:

```
valid_pairs_numeric = qs_pair_code_combis.index.tolist()
ddf_c['is_in_valid_set_of_combis'] = ddf_c[col_name].isin(valid_pairs_numeric)
```

And finally, we can filter the huge `dask.DataFrame`:

```
len(ddf_c.loc[ddf_c.is_in_valid_set_of_combis == True])
# > 246641219 (Correct after filtering)
```